# diagnostic plots for R::fixest

Tags: r, statistics, fixest

Is there any way to get diagnostic plots for the package `fixest`? e.g. leverage plots, actual v predicted, qq plots, residual plots?
I notice that if I have plot(x) where x is a `fixest` object, it gives me an error. `'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`
Thanks!
Of course, one workaround is to just use `lm`, but if I have a large number of fixed effects, lm ends up breaking. I am wondering if there is a native solution compatible with `fixest`.